# Request for a tag to be removed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [political](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political) is redundant and should be removed, considering the entire site is about politics. This tag simply encourages not being specific about the purpose of a question in the tags and simply being lazy, and will also make it harder to find questions on the correct topic if they are simply marked as “political”

Comment: As it is on a single question if it is removed from that question as not appropriate it will be deleted from the system.

Comment: I have removed the tag from the question and it should be deleted when the scripts run to check for unused tags.